# Overflow scroll on element

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

Here what I've now:

[image]

and how it should looks:

[image]

```
<div class="overflow-auto flex flex-col h-full">
      <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col px-7 divide-y-2 divide-metal bg-white">
        <div
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          :item="item"
          class="flex-1 py-4 lg:py-8"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col bg-white lg:bg-gray-light">
        <div class="!bg-white lg:!bg-gray-light lg:border-b-2 lg:border-metal">
          <template #content>
            <h4
              class="h4 uppercase !font-black !text-[26px] 2xl:!text-[36px] leading-10 tracking-[-0.43px]"
              v-text="$t('We Also Recommend')"
            />
          </template>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col px-7 divide-y-2 divide-metal">
          <div
            v-for="product in recommendProducts"
            :key="product.sku"
            :item="product"
            class="flex-1 py-4 lg:py-8"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky top-0 bottom-auto">
      <div class="p-10">
        <div class="desktop-only flex justify-between items-center pb-10 uppercase">
          <p
            class="subtitle1"
            v-text="$t('Subtotal')"
          />
          <div
            :value="totals.subtotal"
            class="subtitle1"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <div
            v-text="$t('Proceed to Checkout')"
            class="btn btn--lg btn--black mb-3.5 text-[15px]"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the problem is that bottom `div` should cover products and section 'We also recommend' with products should have scroll. Now bottom `div` extends beyond the view. On bottom `div` I've `position: sticky` and on section 'We also recommend' `overflow: auto`. Where's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the bottom sheet does cover the last part of the scrolling content, right? There is an easy solution:

Just add

```
padding-bottom: XXpx; # XX == size of sticky bottom sheet
```

to the scroll container

Comment: nope, problem is that I don't have scrolling content which should be in 'We also recommend' section and bottom sheet should cover in some part this section